# Using continue Statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, continue

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm experimenting with the continue statement, and from my understanding, it's suppose to "skip" an iteration and than continue. I wrote a piece of code from a Udemy course I'm doing. The for loop is suppose to fill the percentages2 array, and it does work.

However, I'm trying to have the array not be filled up with values less than 2. If it works I should be getting back 2 elements in my percentages2 array instead of 4.

Anyone know why the continue statement isn't working?

```js
const populations2 = [332, 144, 1441, 67];
const percentages2 = [];

const percentageOfWorld4 = function (population) {
  return (population / 7900) * 100;
};

for (let p = 0; p < populations2.length; p++) {
  if (percentages2[p] < 2) continue;

  percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]));
}

console.log(percentages2);
```

Comment: Your `percentages2` array is empty when you’re checking it in the for loop, so `percentages2[p]` will always return `undefined`. And `undefined < 2` always evaluates to false and so you never reach the `continue` statement. What’re you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the condition you need to check the value of what `percentageOfWorld4` returns instead of `percentages2[p]` before pushing the value to `percentages2` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyy,

- Your are looping an array `populations2` right
- first mistake inside the loop your are not checking the return result from function `percentageOfWorld4` it should be  `(percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]) < 2)`

  - And you should pass the `pth` value of `populations2` then use `continue`
- later you can push the other element to a different array `percentages2.push(populations2[p]);`

```js
const populations2 = [332, 144, 1441, 67];
const percentages2 = [];

const percentageOfWorld4 = function(population) {
    return (population / 7900 ) * 100;
};

for (let p = 0; p < populations2.length; p++) {

    if(percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]) < 2) continue;

    percentages2.push(populations2[p]);

}; console.log(percentages2); // [4.2025316455696204, 18.240506329113924]
```

It is a good practice to store the return value in a variable rather then calling the function twice

```js
const populations2 = [332, 144, 1441, 67];
const percentages2 = [];

const percentageOfWorld4 = function(population) {
    return (population / 7900 ) * 100;
};

for (let p = 0; p < populations2.length; p++) {
    let result = percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]);

    if(result < 2) continue;

    percentages2.push(result);

}; console.log(percentages2); // [4.2025316455696204, 18.240506329113924]
```

Comment: It looks like OP want's to store percents to `percents2` array, not populations.

Comment: Then just push `percentages2.push(percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]));` right

Comment: Why to call the function twice when you can store the return value in a variable?

Comment: `let result = percentageOfWorld4(populations2[p]);
if(result < 2) continue;
    percentages2.push(result);`


Comment: @ullaskunder Thank you, I realized my mistake now. Essentially, I was pushing the results into my percentages2 array, while at the same time, using it as a condition (I think my terminology is correct). What I have to do is check the values themselves first, and that will make the continue statement work. Thank you and everyone for the time. I'm a complete novice. From now on I will also store my results in a variable for good practice.

Comment: Also, you guys said that in my original code, I called the function twice? I don't see it. I only type down percentagesOfWorld4 once. Again I'm still a novice, can someone please explain as a side note how I called it twice? Oh wait, do you say twice because I'm calling it numerous times in the loop with the values stored in the p variable?

Comment: hyy @Handsome Dragon , No @teemu commented on my old answer before the edited one. I called the `percentageOfWorld4` function twice, once in `if` condition and in `push` statement then later I used variable to store the result, then pass that variable rather then calling it again and again. ^_^

Comment: @ullaskunder Copy that, thank you! 