# I don't understand, CONTINUE for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Can anybody help me to explain continue, because I don't really understand.
and why this thing work only with 0 and 1? *creating loop for even numbers*

```
for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

if(i % 2 == 1) continue;

alert(i);
}
```

Thank U:)

somebody help me, I'm really confused hehehe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using continue Statement in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936416/using-continue-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# loop - break vs. continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414/c-sharp-loop-break-vs-continue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continue statement in JavaScript is like a skip button for loops. Imagine you're counting from 2 to 10. If you find a number that's odd (like 3 or 5), you press the skip button. This means you won't pay attention to that odd number and instead move on to the next one. So, with your code, you're counting from 2 to 10, but only showing the numbers that aren't odd. And by the way, 0 and 1 aren't odd or even – they're kind of special.

Answer (score 0):

With the `continue` statements basically we say to stop the current loop execution but we also say to keep going with the next iteration. So, when the interpreter finds a `continue` statement inside a loop, it stops the loop right there and skips everything under that `continue` statement. Everything under `continue` is ignored and the next iteration starts!

Regarding your question 'why does it work only with 1 and 0' I don't know what you mean but I think you are referring to the result of the operation `i % 2`. There is nothing special about 1 and 0. But I think you are missing what the `%` operator does. It returns the remainder of dividing the two operands. So, in your example, it always returns 1 or 0 because you've chosen to divide every number by 2. And the remainder of an odd number divided by 2 is 1 and the remainder of an even number divided by 2 is 0. That's it. But if you change 2 with another number (let's say 5) you will see that there is no more 1 or 0 as a remainder (check the example that I've written). Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder for the remainder operator and what it does.

Bye!

```js
//This is your remainder operation with 2

for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i % 2);
}

//This is another remainder operation with 5. You can see that the result is not only 1 or 0

for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i % 5);
}
```

`